# JavaFX "quickfixes" with tooltips and hyperlinks

Tags: user-interface, javafx, tooltip

does JavaFX provide something like [Eclipse Quickfixes](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-quickfix-assist.htm)? Meaning that you hover over a thing that is broken and got some solutions for it that you can apply immediately.
I know that there are tooltips but they can only contain text, I would need something clickable. Another solution would be something like Dialogs, but I don't want to open another window. I want it to appear on the current stage.
Any suggestions?

**Edit:** to make it clear, I want to adopt the concept of eclipse quickfixes onto a JavaFX based application, maybe showing a "quickfix" when hovering over a circle instance. I *don't* want to check any (java/javafx) source code.

**Edit2:** I've got a hyperlink on a tooltip now:

```
HBox box = new HBox();
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
tooltip.setText("Select an option:");
tooltip.setGraphic(new Hyperlink("Option 1"));
Tooltip.install(box, tooltip);
```

I've got three new problems now:

1. How to make the tooltip not disappear when leaving the HBox and staying there when entering the mouse into the tooltip?
2. How to add mulitple graphics / hyperlinks? Is it even possible?
3. How to first show the text and then, in a new line, display the graphics?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. JavaFX is just a Java library, so Eclipse will provide the same fixes for your Java code if you are using JavaFX as it would for any other Java code.

Comment: It does make sense. I am talking about the concept of quickfixes, not fixing java code. For example, I am displaying some data and there may is some error but we need human interaction to verify. I want to do this by a "quickfix".

Comment: Oh, Ok. That wasn't clear (to me, anyway). Why not just use a tooltip, and put hyperlinks (or other controls) in it?

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear. The idea with hyperlinks in tooltips I've had already, but I wasn't able to implement it. Do you have any example?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What went wrong? Post a [MCVE] showing why it didn't work.

Comment: Nevermind. I'm pretty new to JavaFX and just found that there is a `setGraphic(node)` method on tooltips. I thougt I had to use the setText method. I will implement it and post the code snippet as answer on this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add any node to a tooltip using the `setGraphic()` method. Here is a simple example demonstrating using a tooltip for "quick fix" functionality:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TooltipWithQuickfix extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("invalid"), true);

        textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<Integer>(c -> {
            if (c.getText().matches("\\d*")) {
                return c ;
            }
            return null ;
        }));

        textField.textProperty().isEmpty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) ->
            textField.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("invalid"), isNowEmpty));

        Tooltip quickFix = new Tooltip();
        Hyperlink setToDefault = new Hyperlink("Set to default");
        Hyperlink setToRandom = new Hyperlink("Set to random");
        setToDefault.setOnAction(e -> {
            textField.setText("42");
            quickFix.hide();
        });
        Random rng = new Random();
        setToRandom.setOnAction(e -> {
            textField.setText(Integer.toString(rng.nextInt(100)));
            quickFix.hide();
        });

        VBox quickFixContent = new VBox(new Label("Field cannot be empty"), setToDefault, setToRandom);
        quickFixContent.setOnMouseExited(e -> quickFix.hide());
        quickFix.setGraphic(quickFixContent);

        textField.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
            if (textField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                quickFix.show(textField, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
            }
        });



        VBox root = new VBox(textField);

        root.getStylesheets().add("style.css");

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with the stylesheet (style.css):

```
.root {
    -fx-alignment: center ;
    -fx-padding: 24 10 ;
}

.text-field:invalid {
    -fx-control-inner-background: #ff7979 ;
    -fx-focus-color: red ;
}
```